# How to implement startService(i) not on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In the while(true) statement I am creating an intent that will run a case in the onHandleIntent. However, i am not able to start the intent, using startService(i), without extending the Activity Class to my LocationTracker class. When I do LocationTracker extends Activity, i am able to use startService(i) but the application breaks and stops working. I get the error "Activity has leaked Service Connection". Is there anyway to get around this? The method I do need is private in the BackgroundService class, and my MainScreen extends activity uses the same snippet of code to start the services. Is it that i am running two intents simultaneously, if so is there a way i could call the private method in my other class?

```
public class LocationTracker{               
DSApi dsApi=new DSApi((ContextWrapper)mContext,null);
if(dsApi.initialize(AppSettings.IP_ADDRESS,AppSettings.PORT,false)) {       
  interv = (int)dsApi.sendLocationInfo(l);
  if (dsApi.needRemoteWipe()) {
     while(true){
        Intent i = IntentFactory.getBackgroundService();
        i.putExtra(BackgroundService.EXTRA_OPERATION,BackgroundService.OPERATION_BACKUP);
        startService(i);                                    
        AppSettings.addEventLog(EventLog.TYPE_BACKUP, "Data backed up");    
        break;
        }
    AppSettings.setRemoteWipe(true);
     }
      }
Log.d("SendLocationTask", "finished");}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startService()` method is from the `Context` class, and it seems like you have reference to one. Try the following:

```
mContext.startService(i);
```

The reason it works without a `Context` in an `Activity` is because `Activity` extends `Context` and gets that method through inheritance.